# How to update a parent of a parent class in jpa with @oneToOne relationship?

Tags: java, jpa

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out what I have to do with this problem. I want to do something like this:

```
child.merge(object);
parent1.setCdate(new Date());
parent1.merge(child.parent);
parent2.setCdate(new TimeStamp(new Date().getTime()));
parent2.merge(parent1.parent);
```

But I'm having an error updating the ***parent2***. Based on what I researched across the net,
I think this is the one that causing the error.

```
@Version
@Column(name = "CDATE")
private Timestamp cdate;
```

This is what the error was saying:

```
The object [ph.gov.bsp.tcms.core.Document[ refno=2016052002 ]] cannot be updated because it has changed or been deleted since it was last read.
```

Can you help me figure this one out. Thank you!

Comment: what JPA impl you are using? Anyway, I don't think timestamp field annotated with `@Version` is supposed to be manually updated coz it is used for optimistic concurrency checking.  Hibernate will simply ignore any change, I guess you are using other JPA impl?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I thought that I have to manually update the field with @Version annotation. So, that was the one that causing the error. I excluded that part and my code works fine now. Thanks a lot!